# How can I turn off the flash on a JButton in a Swing app?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am using Java Swing to make an application and I've added `JButton` components to it.

I set the buttons to not be focusable and not paint focus, like so:

```
button.setFocusable(false);
button.setFocusPainted(false);
```

However, there is a blue "flash" whenever I click a button which I want to get rid of. I am on a Mac and using the cross platform UI. How can I remove this flash when clicking?

Comment: Those indications are there for good reason. What's your compelling reason for removing them? BTW - I see you have yet to accept an answer. Please start doing so.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I plan to have a different method of indication and the "flash" just serves as a bad looking distraction.

Comment: *"I plan to have a different method of indication"* Cool. Thanks for clarifying. There are a number of ways to achieve that. Out of pure curiosity.. what is that method of indication? **More generally:** For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: *"There are a number of ways to achieve that."* E.G. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) puts a red border around the 'pressed' icon. Also, does that example give you the tips you need to get rid of the 'flash'?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'll add an example when I'm back home, thanks for the advice. The other method of indication will be an animation hovering over the JButton because we're making games for a Java class project.

Comment: `jButton1.setContentAreaFilled(false);`

Comment: *ill be an animation hovering over the JButton because we're making game* Maybe you can just use the setRolloverIcon(…) method.